# how to catch the names in audio materials?

Tags: names

I'm learning English via listening to audio materials, such as "A murder is announced" BBC radio program recorded. However, I'm quite bad at remember the names. After 3 to 5 minutes, I'm soon lost at a "who is who" status.

For this piece itself, I could "do the homework" get all the characters from wiki. But in general, how could I improve my "name recognition"? In everyday life, I'm also quite bad at remembering names.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question other than "practice makes perfect".  In our multicultural society the list of "common names" has become staggeringly broad, so perhaps it's better simply to start by recognizing someone has said a person's name.  Of course there are all the other kinds of proper nouns, like place names, business names, names of government agencies, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you should write them down. Following plots can be confusing, I agree.

Comment: Do you have the same problem in your native language? If not, what do you suppose is the difference?

Comment: @user3169 I don’t have the same problem in Chinese... not sure why